# Why is the progress decreasing once reached a certain number?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am downloading a file from Firebase Firestore that contains the URL of the file. The file size is more than 100 MB. I am using Asyctask to execute the code, but once it reaches a certain value, it decreases.

I tried getting the absolute value of the progress, but still, it decreases.

```
public static final class DownloadGameTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private Context mContext;

    DownloadGameTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //Kaylangan ng ID for Oreo above
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //Kapag oreo or above ang verion ng phone
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0});
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.download_icon)
                    .setProgress(0, 0, false);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        Log.d("Avery", values[0] + "");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0});
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);

            notification.setProgress(100, values[0], false);

            //notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification.build());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Log.d("Avery", "Starting Async");

        File gameFile;

        //final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//Download//" + "//ChamberDownloads//Books/" + "/" + strings[0] + "//" + strings[0] + ".apk";
        final String absolutePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        final String fileSize = strings[1]; //Eto yung galing sa params ng Asynctask
        Log.d("Avery", Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            gameFile = new File(absolutePath, "Game" + ".apk");

            if (!gameFile.exists()) {
                gameFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                gameFile.createNewFile();
                Log.d("Avery", "APK does not exists");
            } else {
                Log.d("Avery", "APK  exists");
            }

            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            Log.d("Avery", "Length of file: " + lengthOfFile);

            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(gameFile);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096]; ///

            long total = 0;
            int progress = 0;

            while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                Math.abs(total += count);
                int progress_temp = Math.abs((int) (total * 100) / Integer.parseInt(fileSize));

                if(progress_temp%10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp){
                    progress = progress_temp;
                    Log.v("Avery", "total = "+progress);
                }
                publishProgress(progress);
                // Log.d("Avery", String.valueOf(total));
                outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Avery", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be the progress never decreases.

Comment: Check if `((long) connection.getContentLength()) == connection.getContentLengthLong()`. You may be overflowing an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed overflowing an `int`.

`(int) (total * 100)` overflows as soon as `total` becomes increases past 21,474,836. At that point, the result of the multiplication becomes larger than (2^31 - 1), which is the largest positive value that can be represented by an `int`. Since you are casting the `long` result to an `int`, the value wraps, and the sign can flip.

To fix, simply change your casting order so that the calculation is carried out on `longs`:

`int progress_temp = Math.abs((int) ((total * 100) / Integer.parseInt(fileSize)));`